# Setting an object's nested key / values by arbitrary number of parameters

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have some object like:

```
const someObj = {
  x: null,
  y: {
    z: null
  },
  a: {
    b: {
      c: null
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to create a function to set values using something like:

```
const setKV = (obj, ...keyArray) => {
  /* Not quite sure how to phrase this function */
  const val = keyArray.pop()
}
```

Such that I can set the values:

- `x` with `setKV(someObj, 'x', true)`
- `z` with `setKV(someObj, 'y', 'z', true)`
- `c` with `setKV(someObj, 'a', 'b', 'c', true)`

How would I define an object's nested key by this arbitrary number of parameters?

Comment: Try with recursion!

Comment: make the second parameter an array

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want to do using the `...rest` syntax. It's because you need to collect all but the last parameter for keys - `(obj, ...keys, value` is not valid, since you can't have anything after `...keys`. You can invery it and make the signature `(obj, value, ...keys)` or alternatively use the `arguments` object to do what you want.\

Comment: @vlaz you could split out the keys array from the value with `v = kv.pop()`.  I'm just not sure how to specify an arbitrary depth of an object.

Comment: @Bergi you know I'm all over that :D

Comment: What would be the expected result of `setKV(someObj, 'p', 'q', 'r', true)`.  Would it create new nodes along the way?  Throw an exception?  Silently do nothing?

Comment: @ScottSauyet I'd like to suppose the input arguments always match the object being mutated.  An exception would be best, but not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily using a rest parameter and spread argument like `...rest` below. `setKV` does **not** mutate its input object, `o`; a *new* object is always returned.

```js
const setKV = (o = {}, key, value, ...rest) =>
  rest.length === 0
    ? { ...o, [key]: value }
    : { ...o, [key]: setKV (o[key], value, ...rest) }

console.log
  ( setKV ({ a: 0 }, 'b', 1)
    // { a: 0, b: 1 }

  , setKV ({ a: { b: { c: false } } }, 'a', 'b', 'c', true)
    // { a: { b: { c: true } } }
    
  , setKV ({}, 'a', 'b', 'c', 1)
    // { a: { b: { c: 1 } } }
    
  , setKV ({ a: { b: { c: 0 } } }, 'a', 'b', 'd', 0)
    // { a: { b: { c: 0, d: 0 } } }
    
  , setKV ({ a: { b: { c: 0 } } }, 'a', 'b', 1)
    // { a: { b: 1 } }
    
  , setKV ({ a: 1, b: { c: 2, d: { e: 3 } } }, 'b', 'd', 'e', { f: 4 })
    // { a: 1, b: { c: 2, d: { e: { f: 4 } } } }

  , setKV ({ a: 0 }, 'b')
    // { a: 0, b: undefined }
  )
```

> *"If I did want to mutate the input object ..."*

While mutations should be avoided, the specific needs of your program may warrant their use. In such a case, review `mutKV`, if only to see how it differs from the implementation above

```js
const mutKV = (o = {}, key, value, ...rest) =>
  rest.length === 0
    ? (o[key] = value, o)
    : (o[key] = mutKV (o[key], value, ...rest), o)

const data =
  { a: 0 }

mutKV (data, 'b', 1)
console.log (data) 
// { a: 0, b: 1 }

mutKV (data, 'c', 'd', 2)
console.log (data)
// { a: 0, b: 1, c: { d: 2 } }

mutKV (data, 'c', 'd', 3)
console.log (data)
// { a: 0, b: 1, c: { d: 0 } }

mutKV (data, 'c', 4)
console.log (data)
// { a: 0, b: 1, c: 4 }
```

This opens the book for a short lesson about side effects, and encoding them using `effect`. Below we create an effect `mut` using `effect`, then `mut` is used in each branch of `mutKV`. The behavior of the program is identical to `mutKV` above.

```
const effect = f => x =>
  (f (x), x)

const mut = (key, value) =>
  effect (o => o[key] = value)

const mutKV = (o = {}, key, value, ...rest) =>
  rest.length === 0
    ? mut (key, value) (o)
    : mut (key, mutKV (o[key], value, ...rest)) (o)
```

Comment: This is great.  But it does change the requested API, which had the value as the final parameter.

Comment: @ScottSauyet my answer treats the final argument as the value. Can you explain?

Comment: @user633183: Why so it does.  That'll teach me to glance at something and assume I understand it!  Especially when I don't even look at the examples.

Comment: @user633183: and that's a really nice technique that I haven't seen before with the rest parameters.  I'll remember that one.

Comment: @ScottSauyet no worries, I always welcome a comment from you. I tweaked the examples a little bit to make it easier for the reader to see what is being set.

Comment: @user633183 if I did want to mutate the input object, short of slapping a deep object merge function at the end, how would that return function look?

Comment: @arby: Please, just don't!  :smile:

Comment: @user633183 Haha, I agree that mutation is to be avoided, although, this data is being mutated.

Comment: @user633183: Thanks again.  I always seem to be learning from your answers.  I still love an `unfold` you demonstrated six months ago.

Comment: @arby, that was Scott's reply to you. I updated my answer to include a version that mutates the input. But yes, you should avoid mutations where possible.

Answer (score 0):

lodash provides what you're looking for, no need to rewrite it

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#set

```
_.set(someObj, ['a', 'b', 'c'], true);
```

Comment: This would do it, although I'm more interested in how you would write this in javascript or modern ECMAScript.

Comment: well, could check out lodash's source code then, I guess :)

Comment: And this one (as well as Ramda's [`assocPath`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#assocPath), which looks like `assocPath(['a', 'b', 'c'], true, someObj)`) change the requested API, moving node names into an array, and, in Ramda's case, moving the position of the value to set.

Answer (score 0):

We can create function where rest params are two element arrays where first item is key name and secound is desired value

```
function setKV(obj, ...kvs) {
    return kvs.reduce((obj, [k, v]) => {
        obj[k] = v;
        return obj;
    }, obj);
}
```

```js
function setKV(obj, ...kvs) {
 return kvs.reduce((obj, [k, v]) => {
  obj[k] = v;
  return obj;
 }, obj);
}

console.log(setKV({}, [
 "a",
 1
], [
 "b",
 "b"
]));
```